# MySQL select query gets quite slow with BOTH where and descending order

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, query-performance

I have this select query, ItemType is varchar type and ItemComments is int type:

```
select * from ItemInfo where ItemType="item_type" order by ItemComments desc limit 1
```

You can see **this query has 3 conditions**:

1. where 'ItemType' equals a specific value;
2. order by 'ItemComments'
3. with descending order

The interesting thing is, when I select rows with all three conditions, it's getting very slow. But if I drop any one of the three (except condition 2), the query runs quite fast. See:

```
select * from ItemInfo where ItemType="item_type" order by ItemComments desc limit 1;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 16.318 sec. */

select * from ItemInfo where ItemType="item_type" order by ItemComments limit 1;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.140 sec. */

select * from ItemInfo order by ItemComments desc limit 1;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.015 sec. */
```

Plus,

1. I'm using MySQL 5.7 with InnoDB engine.
2. I have created indexes on both ItemType and ItemComments and table ItemInfo contains 2 million rows.

I have searched many possible explanation like MySQL support for descending index, composite index and so on. But these still can't explain why query #1 runs slowly while query #2 and #3 runs well.

It would be very appreciated if anyone could help me out.

**Updates:create table and explain info**

**Create code:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ItemInfo` (
`ItemID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`ItemType` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`ItemPics` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ItemName` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ItemComments` INT(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ItemScore` DECIMAL(10,1) NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
`ItemPrice` DECIMAL(20,2) NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`ItemDate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '1971-01-01 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`ItemID`, `ItemType`),
INDEX `ItemDate` (`ItemDate`),
INDEX `ItemComments` (`ItemComments`),
INDEX `ItemType` (`ItemType`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Explain result:**

```
mysql> explain select * from ItemInfo where ItemType="item_type" order by ItemComments desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | NULL       | index | ItemType      | ItemComments | 5       | NULL |   83 |     1.20 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+

mysql> explain select * from ItemInfo where ItemType="item_type" order by ItemComments limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | NULL       | index | ItemType      | ItemComments | 5       | NULL |   83 |     1.20 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+

mysql> explain select * from ItemInfo order by ItemComments desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | NULL       | index | NULL          | ItemComments | 5       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
```

**Query from O. Jones**:

```
mysql> explain
    ->  SELECT a.*
    ->      FROM ItemInfo a
    ->      JOIN (
    ->             SELECT MAX(ItemComments) ItemComments, ItemType
    ->               FROM ItemInfo
    ->              GROUP BY ItemType
    ->           ) maxcomm ON a.ItemType = maxcomm.ItemType
    ->                    AND a.ItemComments = maxcomm.ItemComments
    ->     WHERE a.ItemType = 'item_type';
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys                          | key         | key_len | ref                       | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | NULL       | ref   | ItemComments,ItemType                  | ItemType    | 767     | const                     |   27378 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>                            | <auto_key0> | 772     | mydb.a.ItemComments,const |      10 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ItemInfo   | NULL       | index | PRIMARY,ItemDate,ItemComments,ItemType | ItemType    | 767     | NULL                      | 2289466 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```

I'm not sure if I execute this query right but I couldn't get the records within quite a long time.

**Query from Vijay**. But I add ItemType join condition cause with only max_comnt return items from other ItemType:

```
SELECT ifo.* FROM ItemInfo ifo 
JOIN (SELECT ItemType, MAX(ItemComments) AS max_comnt FROM ItemInfo WHERE ItemType="item_type") inn_ifo 
ON ifo.ItemComments = inn_ifo.max_comnt and ifo.ItemType = inn_ifo.ItemType
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 7.441 sec. */

explain result:
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type        | possible_keys         | key                   | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                                               |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | system      | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL  |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ifo        | NULL       | index_merge | ItemComments,ItemType | ItemComments,ItemType | 5,767   | NULL  |    88 |   100.00 | Using intersect(ItemComments,ItemType); Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ItemInfo   | NULL       | ref         | ItemType              | ItemType              | 767     | const | 27378 |   100.00 | NULL                                                |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

And I want to explain why I use order with limit at the first place: I was planning to fetch record from the table randomly with a specific probability. The random index generated from python and send to MySQL as a variable. But then I found it cost so much time so I decided to just use the first record I got.

After inspiring by O. Jones and Vijay, I tried using max function, but it doesn't perform well:

```
select max(ItemComments) from ItemInfo where ItemType='item_type'
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 6.225 sec. */

explain result:
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ItemInfo   | NULL       | ref  | ItemType      | ItemType | 767     | const | 27378 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------+
```

Thanks for all contribute to this question. Hope you could bring more solutions based on information above.

Comment: Can you show an EXPLAIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide CURRENT  `SHOW CREATE TABLE ItemInfo`.

For most of those queries, you need the composite index

```
INDEX(ItemType, ItemComments)
```

For the last one, you need

```
INDEX(ItemComments)
```

For that especially slow query, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

**Discussion** - Why does `INDEX(ItemType, ItemComments)` help with `where ItemType="item_type" order by ItemComments desc limit 1`?

An index is structured in a `BTree` (see Wikipedia), thereby making searching for an individual item very fast, and making scanning in a particular order very fast.

`where ItemType="item_type"` says to filter on `ItemType`, but there are a lot of such in the index.  In this index, they are ordered by `ItemComments` (for a given `ItemType`).  The direction `desc` suggests to start with the highest value of `ItemContents`; that is the 'end' of the index items.  Finally `limit 1` says to stop after one item is found.  (Somewhat like finding the last "S" in your Rolodex.)

So the query is to 'drill down' the BTree to the end of the entries for `ItemType` in the composite `INDEX(ItemType, ItemContents)` and grab one entry -- a very efficient task.

Actually `SELECT *` implies that there is one more step, namely to get all the columns for that one row.  That info is not in the index, but over in the BTree for `ItemInfo` -- which contains all the columns for all the rows, ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.

The "secondary index" (`INDEX(ItemType, ItemComments)`) implicitly contains a copy of the relevant `PRIMARY KEY` columns, so we now have the values of `ItemID` and `ItemType`.  With those, we can drill down this other BTree to find the desired row and fetch all (`*`) the columns.

Comment: I added a composite index as you provided, and that did work! The first query execution becomes very quick. But could you please explain how it works?

Comment: Read http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql .  It might not give you the explanation you desire, but it should give you more clues.

Comment: @BarryZhai - added a lengthy, detailed, discussion of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query ordering ascending can take advantage of your index on `ItemComment`.

`SELECT * ... ORDER BY ...  LIMIT 1` is a notorious performance antipattern. Why? The server must sort a whole mess of rows, just to discard all but the first.

You might try this (for your descending order variant).  It's a little more verbose but much more efficient.

```
   SELECT a.* 
     FROM ItemInfo a
     JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(ItemComments) ItemComments, ItemType
              FROM ItemInfo
             GROUP BY ItemType
          ) maxcomm ON a.ItemType = maxcomm.ItemType
                   AND a.ItemComments = maxcomm.ItemComments
    WHERE a.ItemType = 'item type'
```

Why does this work? It uses `GROUP BY / MAX()` to find the maximum value rather that `ORDER BY ...  DESC LIMIT 1` . The subquery does your search.

To make this work as efficiently as possible you need a compound (multicolumn) index on `(ItemType, ItemComments)`.  Create that with

```
ALTER TABLE ItemInfo CREATE INDEX ItemTypeCommentIndex (ItemType, ItemComments);
```

When you create the new index, drop your index on `ItemType`, because the new index is redundant with that one.

MySQL's query planner is smart enough to see the outer `WHERE` clause before it runs the inner `GROUP BY` query, so it doesn't have to aggregate the whole table.

With that compound index MySQL can use a *loose index scan* to satisfy the subquery. Those are almost miraculously fast. You should read up on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will select all the rows with based on the where condition. After that it will sort the rows according to order by statement , then it will select the first row. A better query would be something like

```
SELECT ifo.* FROM ItemInfo ifo 
JOIN (SELECT MAX(ItemComments) AS max_comnt FROM ItemInfo WHERE ItemType="item_type") inn_ifo 
ON ifo.ItemComments = inn_ifo.max_comnt
```

As this query only finds maximum value from the column. Finding MAX() is only O(n) but the fastest algorithm for sorting is of O(nlogn) . So if you will avoid the order by statemet the query will perform faster.
Hope this helped.